# MAGENTO - Sort by name or brand separated by line

Tags: magento

I was wondering if is possible to sort products in MAGENTO ( not from filter ) by the brand name or other atribute and to be delimited ( separated ) somehow, like in this example :

http://www.fashionvictim.ro/barbati/imbracaminte/pulovere.html

If is possible, what is the code for doing this ?

Thank you

Comment: what version of magento?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414008/magento-get-all-categories-containing-products-by-brand

Comment: Magento Community ver. 1.7.0.2